# Access 1 class values in another class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using 2 class 1 contain properties and other contain validation i am sending values in properties with aspx page 
please tell me how to access my property class values in second class without create a new instance because if we create new instance no value is find in properties

please tell me solution

Comment: Could you post your two classes and you aspx page?  I'm not too clear on what you mean

Comment: i mean 2 separate classes and 1 aspx page

Answer (score 1):

Look you can done your work easily with this simple line of code, hope you will find your thing.
create new method in first class.

```
    public string firstClassMethod()
    {
        return (new SecondClass()).SecondClassMethodName(this);
    }
```

Good luck...!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the valdation class a nested class of the primary one. This makes more sense regarding encapsulation than two siblings classes.

```
class Container
{
    protectet string Prop
    {
      set
      {
         //call validation 
         //and set value
      }
    }

    class Validation
    {
        Nested() { }
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: i am using both classess separately

Comment: You could make the read access for the properties public and the write access protected like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx